# How to make Darkmode Js Unsticky?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am using [Darkmode.Js](https://darkmodejs.learn.uno)  for my website.
But it get's sticked at the bottom left of the page.

I want that when I scroll down the page, the darkmode icon should not scroll down.

How can I make it unsticky and place it on the place I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just overwrite the respective CSS rules. Your browser's dev tools let you check, how the icon is positioned and how you can adjust.  In your case, this could result in something like this (keeping in mind CSS's [rules for specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)):

```
body .darkmode-toggle {
  bottom: inherit;
  top: 1em;
}
```

adjust the exact position as you see fit.

Comment: Hello @Sirko Thanks for the Answer. But I want to unsticky it. By using above code I am just able to change it's position. It's still sticky.

Comment: @Andy You could also adjust `position: absolute` to something else. If you reset to something like `position: static` the element will follow the default page flow.

Comment: Actually @Sirko I want that when I scroll down the page, the darkmode icon should not scroll down. I want to remove it's sticky ness.

Comment: @Andy When I test with the first example they give on their page ( https://tradivegan.com/ ) and just adjust `position: static` on the `.darkmode-toggle` element, the button is within the normal flow. As soon as I scroll down, I don't see it anymore. So if this does not work for you, there is some other reason in your code / setup.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mention some additional properties you can see [here](https://darkmodejs.learn.uno/#%E2%9A%99%EF%B8%8F-options) - The `bottom, right, left, top` properties seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually @Maxime Eychenne I want to remove stickyness of the darkmode icon and not adjust it's position.